# Question about the parameter "Context" in ArrayAdapter constructor

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

First, Here is my code

```
class MergedView (context : Context,attributeSet: AttributeSet?) : LinearLayout(context,attributeSet) {

var myCalendar : HorizontalCalendar? = null
var scheduleList : ListView?= null

init {

    val infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
    val li = context.getSystemService(infService) as LayoutInflater
    val v = li.inflate(R.layout.calendar_sequence, this, false)


    addView(v)

    val startDate = Calendar.getInstance()
    startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -5)


    val endDate = Calendar.getInstance()
    endDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5)

    myCalendar = HorizontalCalendar.Builder(this, R.id.calendarView)
        .range(startDate, endDate)
        .datesNumberOnScreen(5)
        .build()

    myCalendar?.setCalendarListener(object : HorizontalCalendarListener() {
        override fun onDateSelected(date: Calendar, position: Int) {

        }
    })

    val texts = arrayOf("None", "None","None")

    val adapter = 
       ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,texts)

    scheduleList = findViewById(R.id.testList)

    scheduleList?.setAdapter(adapter)

}
```

}

I am making custom view called merged View which has ListView and HorizontalCalendarView(another custom view)

So, on strictly saying, according to android development document, one of the constructors of ArrayAdapter is
    "ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] 
                  objects)".  Only one thing I can't understand is Context parameter. According to my understanding, context parameter is a context(Activity) which adapter view is attached. but, then, if adapter View  is attatched on custom View (in my case Merged View), then we can say, context is not a thing that adapter view is attached. So I think passing a context to ArrayAdapter constructor is not right(I think passing a custom view sounds more logical).

So here is my question
1. what is the thing I am misunderstanding?? 
2. what is the correct notion??

Comment: The `Context` is not necessarily what the `AdapterView` is "attached" to. In the `ArrayAdapter`, it's just used for access to resources; e.g., an appropriate `LayoutInflater`.

Comment: So, in my case, context is not the thing ListView is attached  to, instead Merged View is the thing ListView is attached to??

Comment: In terms of the `View` hierarchy, yes, your `ListView` is attached to your `MergedView` (though there may be other `ViewGroup`s in between). The `Context` is just something `ArrayAdapter` needs so it knows how to inflate and style its own item `View`s internally.

Comment: so... um.. the parameter context must be the activity that view(ListVIew's itemview) is appeared??

Comment: It doesn't _have to_ be the `Activity`, and it may very well not be, depending on how your `MergedView` is instantiated. It might be a wrapper around your `Activity`, or some other `Context`. Whenever you instantiate an `ArrayAdapter` inside an `Activity`, though, you just pass the `Activity`, because it is a `Context` that has all of the styling information it needs to make the item `View`s look like your other `View`s.

Comment: then if Merged View is child view of another custom view, do we have to pass context parameter??

Comment: Yes. All `View`s must have a `Context`.